# vk_api - загрузка txt файла в сообщение

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть у меня бот, и вот в конце он отправляет txt файл с некоторым содержимым(не пустой), вроде все работает, но нет. Загрузить файл не получается, т.к. пишет 404, например:https://vk.com/doc-224597286_675455732?hash=yYRJAzlVHoS81hfjEVFMKR8aLInaqop3EWQvbAz14wk&dl=2J0aH7VepJXe8Irji7DIbzYKCm38K2XA8nbQMDcAJlT
Код, отвечающий за загрузку:

```
async def upload_file(f_type, file_name, peer_id):
    global vkapi
    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vkapi)
    result = upload.document_message('config.json', title='parse', peer_id=peer_id)
    return f"doc{result['doc']['owner_id']}_{result['doc']['id']}"
```

сама отправка:

```
attach = await upload_file("doc", "answ.txt", peer_id)
await vk.messages_send(
   peer_id=peer_id,
   message="Парсинг прошел успешно",
   random_id=0,
   attachment=attach
              )
```

Подскажите, что не так?(если что, реализую с помощью vkreal в основном)